# AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn); have no access to the file and throws java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java

`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream()` can not open wav file throws null pointer and says that there is no access. The path is right written.

```java
public class GuiAndStreamClass extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            Button play = new Button("Play");
            play.setPrefSize(50, 20);

            EventHandler<ActionEvent> buttonHandler;
            play.setOnAction(buttonHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    try {
                        streamMethod();
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            root.getChildren().add(play);
            root.setPrefSize(500, 500);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
            primaryStage = new Stage();
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("First JavaFX Application");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void streamMethod() throws LineUnavailableException {
        File fileIn = new File("C:/Users/benutzer1/Desktop/WAV");
        
        try {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileIn);
            Clip audioClip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            audioClip.open(audioInputStream);
            audioClip.open();

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The path can't be correct, if you try to access a single file. You should provide the correct path to the file including file extension. For example `"C:/Users/benutzer1/Desktop/audiofile.wav"`. Also, before using the file, maybe insert a check if the path was correct, e.g. with `if(fileIn.exists())`.

Comment: I create and wrote this file path "C:/Users/benutzer1/Desktop/WAV/SteveAngello-RejoiceWAV.wav".                                                  The first part is a Location of the file in the Folder "C:/Users/benutzer1/Desktop/WAV" this has no extension and the second is a name of the file "SteveAngello-RejoiceWAV.wav" with extension .wav. Than i used the if(fileIn.exist()) as you advised and it jumped over so i assume it didint find it.                                                Thanx for help ; )

Comment: ...and i read it from Properties of the file ,is there a any other specific way to read a path of the file?

Comment: I found my mistake ; )) I additionaly add exention .wav in the  name of file so in the end i had double extantion ; ) Now the method if(fileIn.exist()) pass it threw .Thanx a lot for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

The following line should be added in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This programm is not connected with android.Thanx anyway ; )